# PHP/Laravel - Assign new model to a fetched one

Tags: php, laravel

Let's say I make a call to my `User` and return the following:

```
$user = User::with('permissions')->find(1);
```

I expect to get a `user` with `$user->permissions` being the permission of the user.

Next, I create and assign some new permissions to this user by:

```
// Say Input::all() contains an array of new permissions I want to add
// I am using Underscore PHP here
$newPermissions = Arrays::each(Input::all(), function($permission) {
                      $new = new Permission($permission);
                      $user->associate($new);
                      return $new;
                  });
```

Now I want to update the `$user` and return them back:

```
// This does NOT work (it returns the original $user->permissions)
return $user->permissions = $newPermissions;

// But this DOES work
unset($user->permissions);
return $user->permissions = $newPermissions;
```

Is this a PHP thing or Laravel thing? And what can I do? (btw, even if I say `$user->permissions ='anything, text, string, or object doesnt work!'` nothing happens).

Comment: It's Eloquent thing - it doesn't let you set the relations this way. Use this `$user->setRelation('permissions', $newPermissions)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `permissions` is a relationship, not a simple value that you can assign values to. I'd recommend reading the documentation on [relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships), [eager loading](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading), and on [inserting related models](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#inserting-related-models).

That last one, in particular, is what you're trying to do. Instead of assigning a value to  `$user->permissions`, you need to update the relationship with either the `save`, `associate`, or `attach` methods, depending on the type of relationship.